# Docker COPY invalidates cache during building image on Jenkins

Tags: docker

I have Go project. To cache modules I use `COPY go.mod go.sum ./`. But my cache invalidates on Jenkins just one step before - on COPY project:

```
Step 5/16 : WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/project
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5d2fce4711c2
Step 6/16 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install libavutil-dev
 ---> Using cache
 ---> ab9414893097
Step 7/16 : COPY . /go/src/github.com/project
 ---> c7dc5b6a3c88 #
Step 8/16 : COPY go.mod go.sum ./
 ---> fbd7f900ed7a
```

At the same time locally it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of `.` which you are copying to `/go/src/github.com/project` have changed, which is why the cache is invalidated.

`.` is the build-context - the directory you are doing the docker build from. If anything changes in this folder, it will invalidate the cache.

If your source *isn't* changing and you want to preserve the cache, then move this copy above the previous one.

Comment: thanks. it finally resolved it. i tried a lot of combination but lost that one. but how it is possible if i don't change the source? some hidden jenkins file?

Comment: Just realized, the copy is from `.` (I didn't read it properly at first).